# React-Redux. Redux state changes but data not being refreshed on page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new at Redux and quite incompetent with React in general. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I have a simple table with data. I clicked on header and data at state sorted but this changes dont displayed on page. Data displayed only one time and not re-renders.

**body**

```js
let OurBody = ({ filteredArr }) => {

  return (
    <tbody>
      {filteredArr.map(element =>
        <tr key={element._id}>
          <td>{element.company}</td>
          <td>{element.balance}</td>
          <td>{element.registered}</td>
          <td>{element.address.country}</td>
          <td>{element.employers.length}</td>
          <td>--</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    filteredArr: getSortedCompanies(state.json, state.sortCompany)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OurBody);
```

**header**

```js
let Headersort = ({ dispatch }) => (
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td onClick={() => {dispatch(sortCompany());}}>Company</td>
   <td>Balance</td>
   <td>Registered</td>
   <td>Country</td>
   <td>Number of employers</td>
   <td>Show employers</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 Arr: state.json,
  })

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Headersort);
```

**App component**

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPosts());
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, error } = this.props;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>;
    }
  
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <Headersort />
        <OurBody />
      </table>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
  
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.loading,
  error: state.error
})

App = connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
  
export default App;
```

Reducer works correctly. Every time I clicked data at store changes.
No errors displayed.

Code at github https://github.com/DrGreenNow/React-Redux-Table

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be pushed to your repo

Comment: Are you sure that your code updates the store? Also URL you've provided doesn't contain your code, just generic create-react-app code.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  Updated repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `sort` to sort the data, it sorts the data at original reference and when it updates, the data returned by mapStateToProps has the same reference. Now when connect accepts this data from mapStateToProps, it doesn't trigger a re-render because according to it the data hasn't changed.

Making a clone of data while sorting works.

```
//getSortedCompanies

export default (json, sortCompany) => {
  if (sortCompany === null) {
    console.log(sortCompany);
    return json;
  } else if (sortCompany) {
    console.log(sortCompany);
    return [...json].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.company.toLowerCase() < b.company.toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });
  } else {
    return [...json].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.company.toLowerCase() > b.company.toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

[WOrking demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3vj77kwm)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Good job!